# Referer Request

Tags: java, servlets, request, http-referer

I have a servlet survey application I have been working on.  My problem is that `request.getHeader('referer')` is not getting the right referer url the first time it access the application.
However the second time(or any other time) it does get the correct one.

The first time the application requires a user to take a survey, and then redirects them to the resource url. The second time it only redirects the user to the resource, since they have already taken the survey.  I have 2 java files handling the `take.survey` logic, and the second one just redirecting and logging information (`survey.logic`)

Both routine files use `request.getHeader('referer')`. The first time the user is required to take the survey(take.survey).

As I said before, the app will record on the database the target url, instead of the referral url.  The second time it runs smoothly, and gets the correct referral information.

example:

I am calling the app from a page with the following address:

```
refering page:   thispage
```

The app resides at:

```
app/take.survey
```

The following link is inserted into `thispage` to access the app:

```
app/take.survey?refurl=http://google.com
```

RESULTS:

1st time of clicking link it records: `app/take.survey?refurl=http://google.com`
2nd time of clicking link it gets the right value:  `thispage (url)`
3rd time correct value, and so on.

Again, both files use: `request.getHeader('referer')` to get the referral value.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Referrer doesn't apply when you open a window with `window.open()`, only on clicking regular links or form submissions.  Referrer is the site you were on when you clicked the link or submit button that brought you here. So if they came from google, that's why the referrer said google. First entry to your site the referrer will always be either blank (empty string or null) because they typed the address in the address bar (same as when you open a popup via JS), or some other site because they came to your site via a link.  First entry to the site the referrer is not going to be one of your pages.

Comment: I got it working by using the original referral page, saving it in a session though Velocity files, and passed it to the java servlet before inserting it to the database.

FYI:  I did't open anything with window.open() :)